# Can QGIS for Windows use ticks instead of crosses in the Table of Contents?

Tags: qgis, table-of-contents

In a fairly old blog, Martin Dobias shared a post detailing the use of the [QGIS Layer Tree API](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/) where one of the images shows the Table of Contents (or Layers Panel in QGIS jargon) using ticks to show if a layer is enabled or not:

[image: QGIS Blog image]

This seems to be available in QGIS for Linux users but for Windows, it uses crosses:

[image: QGIS 2.18 image]

Is it possible to use ticks for a Windows version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS jargon...or too much ESRI ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with QGIS 2.14.15 and could reproduce at least the ticks: (see image)
You need to go to settings -> options and their use the "CDE Style" as Style. This also change the style of your plugins.

[image]

After restarting it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is an...interesting style! I just tested `Cleanlooks` and that also does ticks and is less visually striking than `CDE`. In fact, most styles uses ticks :)

Comment: @Joseph I agree its a special style seems bulky somehow but at least i for once could help you :) ( at least a bit)